llama 3.1 assert max_prompt_len <= params.max_seq_len with AWS Jumpstart
We have deployed a llama 3.1 8b instruct model to a AWS Sagemaker endpoint using JumpStart, it works for small prompts but with slightly big prompts it  fails(which beats purpose of using this model because we selected because of the biggest context window) with:
assert max_prompt_len <= params.max_seq_len

I think the message is pretty clear and the solution is simple: update those parameters, but I just can't find any documentation on how to update those parameters when the model is deployed via jumpstart(I already tested the inference parameters at prediction time and did not work, so I guess these should be configured during deploy).
Any hints on how to pass this parameters? How are they usually configured(in general, not specifically for jumpstart)?
